# How do I render svg icons in a svg component?

Tags: angular, svg, angular-ui-bootstrap-tab

I am working on an angular app where I have an icon font I created in IcoMoon with a bunch of icons, I want to render those icons in an SVG component such as this:

```
  <svg style="width: 700px; height: 700px" id="svgPanel">
  </svg>
```

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
<svg:text [attr.x]="myObject.pos().x" [attr.y]="myObject.pos().y" class="myIcon"></svg:text>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: there's no text in that tag. could that be it? you also shouldn't need the `svg:` prefix on SVG children anymore

Comment: https://plnkr.co/2Gt7A1NCaDwdWw03Jye9 shows it working

Comment: @gonzofish thanks, but I want to render an icon from a font I created in IcoMoon. For text it works, I know.

Comment: it might be helpful if you could show what that icon's markup looks like...i'm not very familiar with IcoMoon